# How to handle disconnected graphs in spectral clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, graph-theory, spectral-analysis

I am writing a clustering algorithm based on [Normalized spectral clustering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.0189.pdf).
When I try and compute the **generalized eigenvectors** like so:

```
def normCutSM(A):
    """
    Cuts a grapgh using it adjacency matrix X
    :param X: adjacency matrix
    :return: component vector of size N as a nupy array
    """
    D = np.diagflat(np.sum(A, axis=1))  # degree matrix NxN
    L = D - A  # unnormalized Laplacian

    k = 2  # simplified problem with k set to 2
    (eigvals, eigvects) = sc.linalg.eig(a=L,
        b=D)  # eigenvectors and coresponding eigenvalues of generalized eigenproblem Lu=lambdaDu
    U = eigvects[:, eigvals.argsort()][:, 0:k]
    RR = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(U)  # clustering rows of U (Nxk matrix) having eigenvectors in columns

    return RR.predict(U)  # resulting component vector as np.array
```

`sc.linalg.eig` raises `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater`for disconnected graphs:

What is the correct way of handling such graphs? It might be the case that 1 vertex is disconnected from the remaining 1000, so I am unsure if it is correct to simply separate the graph into disconnected components (as this cut wouldn't reveal very much).

I don't want to discard any data.

---

Addition: My application is actually recursive clustering, where i cut the graph in 2 repeatedly, until every node is isolated.
It is during this process that I often end up having a few disconnected vertexies.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is disconnected, then these obviously just be in different clusters. The"min cut" requires cutting 0 edges!

So first split the graph into connected components, then **cluster each component seperately**!

Answer (score 0):

That makes sens. Please note that the concept of clustering in graphs is based on connection. The example you provided is 1) an extreme example 2) even if it happens in **by mistake** you have no way to retrieve the original connection so you have to consider it isolated!

Apply your spectral clustering on each component. 
Connecting different component is a hat-trick but it may introduce too much misinformation to your analysis. However you can try it by once connecting highest degree (central) node of each component to each other and once the lowest degree (prepheral) nodes to examine the result on both extreme scenarios.

Hope it helped.
Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am actually working with recursive clustering (se update), which is how the disconnected vertices come about. does this change your answer?]

Comment: Not really. I would still go the same way.